# Running manage.py command through Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial to set up Gunicorn to run Django on a VPS, this is working perfectly fine and the web server is running on Nginx.

I created a separate manage.py command that I want to run Async using a worker, I am unsure how to integrate this through Gunicorn.

This is a follow up to [Run code on first Django start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603137/run-code-on-first-django-start/42603157), where the recommendation was to create a separate manage.py command and then run it as a separate worker process through Gunicorn.

Comment: I think last statement of the pointed answer is misinterpreted. Gunicorn only binds to WSGI, so I have suggested an edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gunicorn's purpose here is to serve the Django project using WSGI, it doesn't use manage.py at all. You should call anything related to manage.py directly:

```
$ cd <projectdir>
$ source myprojectenv/bin/activate
$ python manage.py <your command here>
```

For setting it as a worker, you can either set a cron job that points the python binary in the virtualenv or you can consider making a [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) setup with the process management tool (supervisord, docker etc) of your choice.